# How to extract and save LBP features of multiple images?

Tags: excel, matlab

I have a folder of 200 images, I want to extract the LBP features of each image and save them in an excel sheet so that I can use them as a DB features and retrieve, based on them, the accurate images in a CBIR project on MATLAB. I used this code for the extraction but the output gives me the feature vector of only one image.

```
image_folder = 'C:\Users\Desktop\images\resized';
ext_img = '*.png';              
files = dir(fullfile(image_folder, ext_img)); 
assert(numel(files) > 0, 'No file was found. Check that the path is correct');
my_img = struct('img', cell(size(files)));  
for i = 1:numel(files) 
Img = imread(fullfile(image_folder, files(i).name));
gray = rgb2gray(Img);
LBP_image = extractLBPFeatures(gray,'Cellsize',[32 32], 'Normaas i lization','None');
numNeigbors = 8 %%Reshape the LBP features into a number of neighbors -by- number of cells array to access histograms for each individual cell.
numBins = numNeigbors*(numNeigbors-1)+3;
Cell_Hists = reshape(LBP_image,numBins,[]);
Cell_Hists = bsxfun(@rdivide,Cell_Hists,sum(Cell_Hists));%Normalize each LBP cell histogram using L1 norm
LBP_image = reshape(Cell_Hists,1,[]);%Reshape the LBP features vector back to 1-by- N feature vector
end
```

my second question is how to store them in excel (in order to have the feature vectors of the 200 images), I used the `xlswrite()`:

```
filename = 'C:\Users\Desktop\Tests\features.xlsx';
F= xlswrite(filename,LBP_image);
```

but as I said, it gives me the vector of only one images with a value of 1x3776

Comment: There is 2 instance of "LBP_image = ..." in the for loop.. does is means it get overwritten twice @ each loop ?

Comment: Thank you for answering, the second instance of LBP_image in the for loop is only to reshape the feature vectors back to 1-by- N feature vector, it doesn't get overwritten twice.

Comment: test the for loop.. chk : 1. what is the final value of i ? is it a value you expected it to be? 2. comment the for loop n manually run the looped code in 1 cycle, check the output then run it with 2 cycle chk the output, does the code produce a gradually increased sized output? is the content when it was run for 1 loop get appended compared to '2 loop' run? If yes for both, then the (original) for loop is not working. If content of '1 loop' output doesn't get appended to '2 loop' output, then the there is a pretty good chance that the value 'append' doesn't occurs in the loop.

Comment: It's fixed, i made a separate array for the results instead of the LBP_image .. thank you p._phidot_ i appreciate it.

Comment: glad it helps. ( :